# Dictionary or Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, nsmutablearray

In what situation does it make sense to use a dictionary versus a NSMutableArray?

Comment: I'll just add that because you're comparing a "dictionary" to a "mutable array", you may want to read about the difference between mutable and immutable (or NSMutableArray vs. NSArray.)  Dictionaries also come in mutable and immutable versions.

Answer (score 2):

Those are 2 different types of containers. Array is a sequential data storage where you can retrieve elements by index. Dictionary is a hash where you retrieve elements by "names". Both have pros and cons (lookup speed, insertion time, enumeration, etc).

Please read on generic Array vs Hash.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirements.

If you need a collection of stuff, any order or even strictly ordered, and you need to iterate over the values, then perhaps an Array suffices.

If your data has a key and a unique key at that (serial number, login name, whatever) then a dictionary is going to give you quick access to the objects by key.